# How to send a POST Request to a web service without data from console application in C#?

Tags: c#, post, google-cloud-storage

I have a requirement in my Google cloud Storage project to make a POST request with empty body along with some  request headers and get the Created(201) response , which contains an Upload ID to initiate resumable uploads.

I could find references to send POST request with data , but not without data from console application.

Does any one know how to get through this problem.

Comment: What did you stop from trying to modify the sample to create a `HttpWebRequest` without sending data, just using `GetResponse()`?

Answer (score 3):

```
    using(var http = new WebClient())
    {
        http.Headers.Add("headername", "headervalue");
        var response = http.UploadData(address, new byte[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google Cloud Storage online docs contain a section describing the resumable upload protocol ([link](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/developer-guide#resumable)). it includes the following sample request for initiating a resumable upload:

```
POST /music.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.commondatastorage.googleapis.com
Date: Fri, 01 Oct 2010 21:56:18 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
x-goog-resumable: start
x-goog-api-version: 2
Authorization: OAuth 1/zVNpoQNsOSxZKqOZgckhpQ
```

You could also take a look at the [boto source code](https://github.com/boto/boto), which contains a Python implementation of the Google Cloud Storage resumable upload protocol (see boto/gs/resumable_upload_handler.py).